# Background SVG technique?

Tags: html, css, svg

To create background patterns (triangle, trapezoid, etc.) I see a lot of devs relying on SVGs. 
Today, I came across a technique that I don't quite understand.

By scaling a shape like this:

[image]

and applying `height: 100%` as well as `transform-origin` a triangle is created. The start-point of the triangle is always the lower-left corner of the containing element. The result is nice and responsive, but I have no idea why this works from a geometric perspective.

I created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/florianmartens/pen/JjYprWj) to demonstrate.

```css
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.shape-img {
  padding-bottom: 10rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  position: inherit;
  width: inherit;

}

.shape-img > svg {
  position: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  width: inherit;
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-relative">
      <div class="shape">
        <div class="shape shape-img">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0 25h25L75 0h25v50H0z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<br />
<br />
<!-- 
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0 25h25L75 0h25v50H0z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
-->
```

**1. How does this approach ensure that the lower-left corner the bottom of the containing element?**

**2. How does this approach ensure that the user sees a triangle shape regardless of the screen-size?**

Comment: this approach is a bit overkill for a simple triangle. One div element with the SVG as background can do better

Comment: @Xen_mar Why wouldn't you want to use an SVG?  It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Brad the approach uses an SVG ... not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easier idea with the same SVG and only one div:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  background: 
     url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0 25h25L75 0h25v50H0z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>') 
     top/  /* place it at the top center (no need "center" because it's by default) */
     200% 200%, /* width height (twice bigger as the container*/
     yellow; /* background color */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

To understand the scale effect see the below:

```css
.box {
  border:5px solid red;
  margin:50px auto;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
} 
.box svg {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:scale(2);
  transform-origin:top center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M0 25h25L75 0h25v50H0z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
</div>
```

---

By the way, you can use an easier SVG where you have only a triangle shape:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  background: 
     url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none"><polygon points="0,1 1,0 1,1" fill="black"/></svg>'),
     yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this amazing answer. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the scale effect. Does the scale effect only work because the SVG is designed in a way that exactly 50% of it is made up of this angled slope? I didn't create the SVG myself - so I'm unsure. Why would someone create an SVG like that and not just a triangle and make it span 100% of the width?

Comment: @Xen_mar yes it only works for that particular SVG so it's not a generic solution to use the scale(2). As I commented, the method you found is a bit overkill. As you can see in my last example, we can have lot easier

Comment: wow - ok, interesting. I marveled at the deeper meaning/advantage behind the weird scaling and SVG. But it really just seems to be a case of overcomplication. Thanks for clearing it up. Your answer was super helpful!